# What is the easiest way to print text to screen in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, printing

I need to print 3 lines of text to a window as a menu.

```
1 - Menu
2 - Pause
3 - Exit
```

Comment: On top of 3D: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847109/displaying-fixed-location-2d-text-in-a-3d-opengl-world-using-glut Without any library besides OpenGL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847899/opengl-how-to-draw-text-using-only-opengl-methods

Answer (score 15):

Considering that you used GLUT in previous questions, the easiest would be using GLUT's built in font rendering functions.

Example:

```
void output(int x, int y, float r, float g, float b, int font, char *string)
{
  glColor3f( r, g, b );
  glRasterPos2f(x, y);
  int len, i;
  len = (int)strlen(string);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, string[i]);
  }
}
```

Where font is one of GLUT font constants:

```
GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13
GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15
GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10
GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24
GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10
GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12
GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18
```

Comment: Can we render the text without using GLUT ? what are the possible ways ?

Answer (score 4):

Up this post because i found a really great tool to render high quality 2D text:

[freetype-gl library](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl)

see sample rendering :

[image: freetype-gl sample image]

Answer (score 2):

[This webpage](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_text.html) outlines the three possible ways, and links to handy libraries that help.

There's no simple built-in way to render text, and there are (as detailed on that page) sevaral possible approaches, it's all a trade-off depending on what properties you require from your text rendering.

Answer (score 1):

A Windows-only but simple method is described here: [Nehe Lesson 13](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=13)

Basically, it uses these three functions:

- `wglUseFontBitmaps`
- `glListBase`
- `glCallLists`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to write text on the screen:

```
glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRasterPos2f(-240, 120); //define position on the screen
        char *string = "Text";
      
      while(*string){
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, *string++);
      }
```